# Problem using CH340 driver for Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, windows

I am at my wits end and hope somebody here can provide some much-needed guidance.
My platform is an Asus ROG AMD laptop running Windows 11.
I recently decided to try working with Arduinos and purchased a Nano Every direct from Arduino.  I installed the Arduino IDE and when I plugged in the Every it showed up in Device Manager under Ports using the FTDI driver (I suspect that the driver was installed when I installed the IDE).
I had some problems with the Every and decided to try a straight Nano. I purchased one from Micro Center and when I plug it in it also appears in Device Manager under Ports, again using the FTDI driver.  When the Arduino IDE could not communicate with the Nano (I did change board and port) I realized that the unit uses an inexpensive Chinese comm chip was told by Micro Center support that I needed to install the CH340 driver.  As recommended I downloaded the driver installation package from wch-ic.com.  When I ran that installation it reported that the driver was already installed, and I do see two ch341ser.inf_amd64_xxxx entries in Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository.
My problem is that I cannot figure out how to make the Nano use the CH340 driver.  When I try to update the driver in Device Manager it tells me that the current driver is the best one.  When I try to force an update by using "Let me pick from a list", browsing to one of the ch341ser.inf_amd64_xxxx folders in DriverStore\FileRepository and selecting CH341SER.INF I am presented with a set of possible models (CH330, CH340, CH340K, CH341, CH341A).  I was unable to find any guidance on which to select, so I (probably unwisely) experimented.  When I choose CH340 or CH341 the update process begins but my laptop abruptly restarts and afterwards the Device Manager entry in Ports is still using the FTDI driver.
I don't know why the CH340 upodate fails and causes a restart.
I don't know if I should try to delete the FTDI driver (and in fact am uncertain how to go about doing that).
I would greatly appreciate whatever help anyone can provide.

IDE output:
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

```
     System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\bobwi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM3
     Using Programmer              : arduino
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
```

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

Comment: may be just set the Processor option in the Tools menu

Comment: OK, tried using Processor ATMega328P (instead of ATMega328P (Old Bootloader)) and upload now works using FTDI driver.

Comment: Also had to make sure that Serial Monitor was not open when uploading.